# when launch chromedriver browser on selenium and try to navigate to some page the browser doesnt response and nothing wrote to chromedriver log

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm usine selenium web driver version 3.0.0 on c# ,and chromedriver 2.8(Latest version).
when try to launch the browser and navigate to some page, the browser launched but dosen't response and nothing wrote to chrome logs.
My code is:

```
var optn = new ChromeOptions();
optn.AddArgument("--verbose");
optn.AddArgument("test-type");
optn.AddArgument("disable-extensions");
optn.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(chromeDriverPath);
service.LogPath = @"C:\temp\chromedriver.log";
service.EnableVerboseLogging = true;
var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, optn);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=aWh0U7WHEJGAuASTuYHIAQ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
                String chromeDriverPath = @"C:\Users\Shani\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\StudentsReporter\Drivers\"; 
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
                options.AddArgument("disable-extensions"); 
                options.AddArgument("--verbose"); 
                options.AddArgument("test-type"); 
                options.AddArgument("start-maximized");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath, options);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: whem I try it I got next exception:

Comment: "unknown error: cannot get automation extension\nfrom unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {\"auxData\":{\"frameId\":\"8420.1\",\"isDefault\":true},\"id\":1,\"name\":\"\",\"origin\":\"chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb\

Comment: Never seen that error before. On your path make sure you point to the folder. Do not add the *.exe into the path name.  Make a folder called Drivers. Drop the chromedriver.exe in it and then set this: driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\MyMySolutionPath\Drivers"), options); If this is not working, post your method that you have now.

Comment: It stil dosen't works and launch browser but didn't navigate to page, this is my code:

Comment: String chromeDriverPath = @"C:\Users\Shani\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\StudentsReporter\Drivers\";
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.AddArgument("disable-extensions");
                options.AddArgument("--verbose");
                options.AddArgument("test-type");
                options.AddArgument("start-maximized");                                                     
                ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath, options);
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

Answer (score 0):

String chromeDriverPath = @"C:\Users\Shani\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\StudentsReporter\Drivers\"; 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); options.AddArgument("disableextensions"); 
options.AddArgument("--verbose"); options.AddArgument("test-type"); options.AddArgument("start-maximized"); ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverPath, options); driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("google.com");